# Check the version of wtforms used in flask - wtforms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

What is the version of wtforms that is used in flask - wtforms?

[WTForms 2](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/whats_new.html) is the new release, but I can't find anywhere if the [flask - wtforms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) use this version or an older version.

How can I find the version that is being used?

Here is the [code of the extension](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the requirements file from project's source:

https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/requirements.txt

WTFroms has to be bigger then 1.0.4, so you can install what ever you like 1.1, 2 etc... previously.

WTForms>=1.0.4

So, WTforms is a requirement, when you install flask-wtf the requirements file will be checked against the python packages you have.

To check the version your using:

```
pip freeze | grep WTForms
```